# Book where wizard moves to the moon

Tags: story-identification

I read a book series about 11 years ago and can't remember the name. I remember that there was a royal family that was assassinated and a young guy found out he was a wizard. I remember him going back in time and learning about a great wizard (I think Bron) and figuring out he was that great wizard. He then discovers alchemy and moves to the moon(or a planet) to pass time until he needs to be born again. I was like 8 so could be way off.

Maybe correct information
 The royal family died in a carriage accident or something on he way to a picnic. 
There was a huge wizard tower near the castle. 
Magi was banned or outlawed or forgotten or scarce. 
Brons symbol was a hammer in a circle? Maybe.

Comment: When was `a long time ago`, like two years, 5 years, 30? Also, check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: I posted most of what I remember. I read through of it and thought of more details but nothing significant. I don't want to post incorrect information.

Comment: Honestly, even if you think it's not 100% relevant, it might be helpful to someone. You're welcome to add those details and mention that you're not sure, etc.